# Component not re-rendering when context is updated

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a component that uses the context, but does not re-render when the context is updated.

### App.tsx

```
const AppContext = createContext({
  isLoggedIn: false,
  hasUserLoggedInBefore: false,
});
const useAppContext = () => useContext(AppContext);

function App() {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [hasUserLoggedInBefore, setHasUserLoggedInBefore] = useState(
    false
  );


  useEffect(() => {
    // to set up initial state
    asyncApiCall 
      .then((result) => {
        if (result["user"]) {
          setIsLoggedIn(true);
        } else {
          setIsLoggedIn(false);
        }

        if (result["hasUserLoggedInBefore"]) {
          setHasUserLoggedInBefore(true);
        } else {
          setHasUserLoggedInBefore(false);
        }
      });

    // to listen for changes
    // this does not seem to re-render <UserControl />
    listenToOnAuthChangeEvent((user) => {
      setIsLoggedIn(true);
      setHasUserLoggedInBefore(true);
    });
  });


  return (
    <AppContext.Provider
      value={{
        isLoggedIn,
        hasUserLoggedInBefore,
      }}
    >
      <div className="App">
        <Routes>
          <Route element={<UserControl />}>
            <Route path="/" element={<Functionality />} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );

}
```

And component that uses the context

### UserControl.tsx

```
function UserControl() {
    const { isLoggedIn, hasUserLoggedInBefore } = useAppContext();

    if (!isLoggedIn) {
        return (
            <Navigate to={hasUserLoggedInBefore ? "/login" : "/signup"} />
        )
    }

    return (
        <Outlet />
    )
}
```

The async API call will fetch the data. If the user is not logged in, display either the sign up or login page based on whether they have ever logged in in the past. If they are logged in, display `<Functionality />`.

From what I can tell, after the API call succeeds and the `set` methods are called, the `UserControl` component does not re-render to display `<Functionality />`, and the `<Signup />` component is displayed again.

Comment: where path in ```<Route element={<UserControl />}>```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating the codesandbox from your previous question to use your `useEffect` and `asyncApiCall` call what I see happen is the user starts on the home path `"/"`, and since they are not authenticated they get redirected to `"/signup"` page. Later the context state updates and you have to navigate back to `"/"` if you want to see the `Functionality` component. This is probably the typical use case where the app is making redirection decisions prior to the first authentication call, the solution is to use a third indeterminant "state" to hold off on redirecting or rendering the outlet.

Change the initial `isLoggedIn` and `hasUserLoggedInBefore` state to undefined.

```
const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState();
const [hasUserLoggedInBefore, setHasUserLoggedInBefore] = useState();
```

Update the `UserControl` auth wrapper to check this specific undefined case and render a loading indicator or null.

```
function UserControl() {
  const { isLoggedIn, hasUserLoggedInBefore } = useAppContext();

  // ... snip unrelated code

  if (isLoggedIn === undefined) return "... Checking Auth ...";

  if (!isLoggedIn) {
    return (
      <Navigate to={hasUserLoggedInBefore ? "/login" : "/signup"} replace />
    );
  }
  return <Outlet />;
}
```

This allows the app to wait for the auth status to populate into state before rendering the redirect to either of the login or signup routes, or the `Outlet` for the protected component.

[image: Edit component-not-re-rendering-when-context-is-updated]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I still have the issue whereby an update in state does not trigger a re-render for the `<UserControl />` component. I should have clarified that I also have a listener in my useEffect() function that listens for userAuth changes - I'll update my question to reflect that.

Comment: To clarify, the issue is not when the user opens the app - it is when the user actually logs in. After logging in, the user just ends up back on the sign up page, even though I have a listener that is triggered on auth change, and sets the state of `isLoggedIn` to true. Only the first change in state from undefined to false/true for `isLoggedIn` has any effect on `<UserControl />`, a change from false -> true or true -> false does not

Comment: Hm, I believe I have a race condition. `<Login/>` attempts to update the same data that `<App/>` uses in its `useEffect()`. So when `<App />` re-renders on a `<Login/>` form submit, it thinks the user isn't logged in because the data has not been updated by then. On the other hand, I can't get `<Login/>` to update the state on a successful login because it gets overwritten by App's API call...

Comment: @user3073511 Yeah, seems like there's more going on with the components you are also trying to render on these routes. Can you include their code in your question so that we have a fully reproducible example? I'm unable to reproduce the issue with the minimal code in my sandbox.

Comment: All good - I've made a bunch of changes so this question (and my subsequent fix) are not relevant anymore. Thanks for your help!